# Cant handle model IntegrityError in django

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models

I have model that contains `name` field with `unique = True` like below

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 , unique= True)
```

When I try to submit duplicate data in my model it raise `IntegrityError` as expected but I can't handleit in except block in my view.

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError
try :
    name = MyModel(name= my_new_name)
except IntegrityError:
    return HttpResponse('Error') # this code never execute
```

My error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed
```

Comment: Are you using MYSQL or Postgres ?

Comment: I am using SQLite for development @GaëtanGR

Comment: Model instance creation (and you'r error as well) happens not when you instantiate model, but when you save it. You can put `save()` inside exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `name = MyModel(name= my_new_name)` won't actually save your object in database.

You should replace it by `name = MyModel.objects.create(name= my_new_name)`